# Insufficient permissions to execute files with root access

Tags: permissions, partitioning, reinstall, teamspeak

Recently I had some system problems with Ubuntu, so I reinstalled the system. I have two hard drives, one is used for the system and the other one for files, movies, etc. Before the reinstall I moved the Teamspeak 3 folder from my system hard drive to the other one.

Now, after the reinstall I cannot launch Teamspeak 3. I have to run a ts3client_runscript.sh file to start it up, but it says that I have no permission. I've looked on the internet, but I didn't find something that can help me.

I also noticed that a lot of the files appear green in the working Teamspeak 3.

Thank you for the help. :)

[Unable to execute .sh with root permissions picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCtVc.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us the *exact* error message you get; the wording can be important. ii) Show us the output of `ls -l ts3client_runscript.sh` so we can see the permissions on the script. iii) [edit:] I just saw your screenshot. Please don't post images of text, copy the text directly into your question instead. Does it work if you run `bash ts3client_runscript.sh`?

Comment: Did you move the files and then move them back after the reinstall? Or are you mounting the other drive within the new system? If so what is the filesystem on the the other drive, and how are you mounting it?

Comment: You still need to provide the following details in order to get help: 1. The detailed directory listing (using the `-l` option). 2. The output of `mount`. 3. What exactly you tried and what the console output was (copy&paste, please, not your interpretation of it).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the UID (user ID) that's been assigned to your user on the previous system differs from the new one. Try terdon's hint and check which user owns the file(s) on the second disk:

```
$ ls -l <directory>
```

If this assumption is correct the owner column will either contain a number instead of your own username, or some other username. Also check that the group is correct (usually identical to the username).

You can change the owner to your new user by using `chown`, either for a single file or (example below) for a complete directory tree:

```
$ sudo chown -R <username> <directory>
```

Use `chgrp` in the same manner to change the group if necessary, or add the groupname to `chown`:

```
$ sudo chown -R <username>:<groupname> <directory>
```

Do **not use** `chmod` for this! You will mess up permissions without solving the initial issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if i did something wrong. Anyways, I ran the chown command to the whole partition, with argument -R not -r, i'm not sure if it was your mistake, but I get an error. (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04)

This doesn't seem to help me. It's the same.

Also, I copied the folder into my home folder and then replaced the .sh script and the actual executing file (ts3client_linux_amd64) and it ran as if the previous configuration files weren't there. So this didn't work either.

Comment: Also, looking around the permissions, in the properties of the partition it says that Owner: Me has 'Create and delete files' permissions, but this doesn't include the 'Access files'.

Comment: @user264307 Sorry, the lowercase option was my fault, should have taken a look at the man page before. But you still need to provide more information in your question, see my new comment there.

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

Another cause for your troubles could be, that the data partition might be mounted with `noexec` mount option in fstab.

To evaluate if this is indeed the cause, you should have a look at two little things:

1. the `/etc/fstab` configuration file, which holds (nearly) all partitions and other stuff that should be mounted at boot time
2. the output of `mount`

### /etc/fstab

`/etc/fstab` is a tabularly formatted configuration file which holds partitions and other stuff (which is not relevant for this issue, though), their mount points and some parameters which define how the `mount` command should be called.

#### example

```
UUID=***** /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,discard 0       1
UUID=***** /boot           ext2    defaults,noatime        0       2
UUID=***** /boot/efi       vfat    noatime,umask=0077      0       1
UUID=***** /home           ext4    defaults,noatime        0       1
```

- I replaced the UUIDs for better readability.
- Instead of a UUID a line can begin with a /dev/ node name as well; for example `/dev/sda1`

Have a look at the line which holds the mount point where your TeamSpeak3 folder is located. For example if you put teamspeak on /home/evgenie/ the last line in my example fstab would be the one you are looking for.
In the fourth column you find the mount parameters (defaults,noatime in my case). If this would read "defaults,noatime,noexec" you would prohibit ALL executions on this partition/mount point.

### mount command

Now let's have a look at the output of the mount command. This is my example, I filtered out all the stuff not relevant to this example:

```
$ mount | grep /home
/dev/sdc1 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
```

This is basically the same as in `/etc/fstab`, but there might be some additional parameters set - "data=ordered" for example.

### If you found `noexec` in there ...

... open your `/etc/fstab` in an editor as root (for example `sudo nano /etc/fstab`) and remove it.
It has some security implications though:
`noexec` prohibits to execute scripts or binaries from that partition. This might be relevant depending on if and how others may use this system.

Comment: That's a worthwhile thing to look into, but how do you do that? And what would you do to alleviate the issue once this cause was confirmed? As it stands your post doesn't qualify as an answer, sorry. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: As I'm an autodidact, I often forget not everyone values the opportunity to learn something by diving into man pages. ;-)
On your request I will expand the answer and go into further details. Just gonna take some minutes. As the information asked for by Murphy was still not provided, I need to do a lot of guessing though.

Comment: That's why it may be smarter to wait for clarification instead of pouring time into potentially abandoned questions. ;-)

Comment: /etc/fstab doesn't have any information about my second drive.